# Flashback Data Archive Not Capturing client_identifier

Tags: oracle

Audit attribute client_identifier from the USERENV context is not being stored with flashback data archive records after restarting database instance. Oracle standard edition version 19.17

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after instance is restarted, the instance will forget value of flashback data archive context level if it was set to a value different than TYPICAL. In my case, before restarting instance, context level was set in ALL. So, after instance restart, I had to set value of context level to ALL again using the following command

```
EXEC DBMS_FLASHBACK_ARCHIVE.set_context_level('ALL');
```

for more info about context level, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_FLASHBACK_ARCHIVE.html#GUID-B89C99AE-EE5A-4EEC-B66E-3CA1F6D90877